# Is a male fox widely called a "dog fox"?

Tags: grammatical-gender

Someone on the BBC lunchtime news today referred to a ***dog fox***.

The word *dog* is both generic and applied to both sexes, as well as being used to describe a male. Only context reveals whether a person is talking about dogs in general or a male dog, as opposed to a *bitch*.

Is it not the same with *fox and vixen*? Or are we required, when specifying a male fox to use *dog fox*?

The OED would not appear to recognise any sense of *fox* as referring to a male only, in the way that it does with *dog*.

Are there other species where the gender distinction is only achieved by reference to a different genus?

Comment: Just seen your last sentence - that's my evening research planned!

Comment: If you consider "cow" to be the singular designation for bovine cattle (regardless of gender), then that word as applied to animals such as a female moose would qualify.

Comment: Have you tried asking a fox to see what the fox says?

Comment: Why don't we say "she's vixenly?"

Comment: @SvenYargs Yes, I believe *cow* is a good example. It gets used for various animals, as does *bull* e.g. for elephants. I think *sow* and *boar* also extend well beyond pigs.  Personally I wouldn't use *cow* as a generic word for bovines. But that's just because I was a country boy.

Answer (score 17):

When used together, "fox and vixen" sufficiently implies males and female.

However, "I saw a fox" does not imply gender, just like "dog" as you mention. In usual context, one does not need to identify the gender so "fox" is all that is required:

> 1. Fox populations have increased by x%....
> 2. Foxes are great
> 3. I have a pet fox

If context **does** require the gender, then you will need to use dog, [tod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fox_and_the_Hound) or [reynard](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Reynard) fox to illustrate the gender (although "tod" and "reynard" have literary origins and are less likely to be understood):

> Vulpine studies have shown that the vixen outlives the dog fox by x number of years...

Although in reality you're probably better off saying:

> Vulpine studies have shown that the female outlives the male fox by x number of years...

And to support my answer, [Chris Packham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Packham) has [replied to my tweet](https://twitter.com/ChrisGPackham/status/737683278371643397), "dog and vixen" - so there you have it from a highly-authorative source!

Comment: First time I've seen an answer with a tweet message from an expert. :-)

Answer (score 6):

***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dog%20fox%2Cmale%20fox&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)*** actually shows that "dog fox" is more used than "male fox".

***[Dog fox](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dog-fox):***

> - a male fox:
>
>   - *No doubt an old vixen, with no cubs of her own, killed his; the dog fox will not do this.*

Its usage dates back to the end of the 16th century.

- In ordinary speech "male fox" is probably more common usage.